# Unwanted dialog when connecting smartphone with Bluetooth in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, smartphone, dialog

When I connect my Samsung Galaxy S5 to my Windows 7 notebook, the following  window appears:

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. It is described in this article:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/disable-pop-up-remote-control-for-bluetooth-audio/0428d23b-6e4a-4df7-84c1-953fbdecfd55?auth=1

You need to disable the service "Remotely controllable device" in the properties of your Bluetooth device:

- Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers.
- Right clicked on the device, select "Properties" and go to the services tab.
- Uncheck Remotely Controllable Device.

Answer (score 1):

Your notebook it seeing your phone as a media player. This triggers the Autoplay feature in Windows 7.

To stop the media player from opening when you plug your phone in, you have to disable the Autoplay feature from the Control Panel.

With your phone connected, go to `Control Panel`, switch to `Large Icon` view and then select the `Autoplay` icon. From there, you can turn off Autoplay completely (at the top with the checkbox) or by media type/device. Your phone will be listed at the bottom under devices.

[image]

As you can see, I chose `Take no action` for my phone when it is plugged in. Make sure to click <kbd>Save</kbd> before you close the window.

Comment: Hello. Thank you Charlie for the extensive answer. I have made this setting, but the dialog still comes up. I think it's not the normal windows media player, but some other small remote control tool.